# Measurable set in product space.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I  am stuck on the following question.  Any helps would be highly appreciated!
Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L}, m)$ denote he set of real numbers with the Lebesgue measure. Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f \in L^1(X)$. Let $\Gamma= \{((x,f(x))): x\in X\} \subset X \times \mathbb{R}$. Is $\Gamma$ measurable with respect to $ \mathcal{M} \times  \mathcal{L}$?  How do  we compute $(\mu  \times m)(\Gamma)$?

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Is $\nu$ same as $m$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Can reduce to the case $X$ is bounded and $f$ is also bounded, $0<f <1$.

Consider a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ converging pointwise increasingly to $f$. If
$$U(f) = \{ (x,t)\ | \ 0< t< f(x)\}$$
then $U(f) = \cup_n U(f_n)$, and $U(f_n)$ is a finite union of rectangles.  Therefore, $U(f)$ is measurable. Moreover, its measure is $\int_X f$.  Now do the same for the function $1-f$.  Notice that

$$U(f) \cup U(1-f) = (X\times (0,1)) \backslash\Gamma(f)$$
We conclude that $\Gamma(f)$ is measurable, of measure $0$.